# Relations on a set. Discrete Mathematics.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

just want to verify that my understanding of relations is correct, grammar and correct logical form.  Thanks!

Determine whether the relation R on the set of all Web pages is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and/or transitive, where $(a, b) \in R$ if and only if every one who has visited Web page a has also visited Web page b.

**Reflexive:** One who has visited Web page a has also visited Web page a. Thus this is reflexive.

**Symmetric:** One who visits Web page a has also visited web page b, however it is not necessarily the case that one who visits Web page b has visited Web page a, thus this is not symmetric.

**Transitive:** If one has visited Web page a, they visited Web page b, and having visited Web page b they also visited Web page c.  Thus, one who has visited Web page a has visited Web page c.  Thus this relation is transitive.

**Antisymmetric** We know one who visits Web page a, also visits Web page b, from this if we know that one who visits Web page b also visits Web page a, then Web page a is Web page b.  Thus, this relationship is antisymmetric.

Comment: You're right about everything except antisymmetry. Just because two sites have exactly the same visitors doesn't mean they're *the same site*.

Answer (score 0):

The first three seem correct to me, but the last one does not: there may be two different websites that happen to have been visited by precisely the same users. So $(a, b)\in R$ and $(b, a)\in R$ does not imply $a=b$ in general, in which case $R$ is not antisymmetric.

Comment: I think your right, I didn't apply the definition of antisymmetric properly, like you said it would have to be the case:  "all users who visits web page a visit web page b, and all users who visit web page b visit web page a", does not mean that they are the same web page.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I have only one more question, regarding the question write up, it states "if and only if", have I responded correctly with my solutions?  Would I need to now assume a position of reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric and transitive?  Or is the question incomplete?

Comment: Well, for my taste your write-up is fine, I don't know about your teacher..